# $.get Callback function not executed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, get

I executed the following simple program expecting the callback function of get method will execute. But it only make the AJAX call and callback function is not executed. Due to this returned data is not showing in alert box. Appreciate your help. Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("#bt1").click(function() {
    url = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/5b0c30b2-1069-4640-9bb6-18ceb95c25c4";
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<div id="div1"> This is dummy data </div>
<button id="bt1"> Click here </button>
```

Comment: You need to debug this. Look at the developer tools in your browser. Are there any errors reported on the console? Does the request show up on the Network tab? Does it have the response you expect it to have? The jqXHR object returned from `get()` supports a `fail()` callback. Write one to handle the error state and see if that triggers.

Comment: @Quentin, AJAX call is successful and it returns the data("Sun Jan  3 18:05:31 IST 2021"). Confirmed the same in network tab too. Also no error is reported on console. Not sure, why callback is not executing.

Comment: CORS issue? you are trying to access resource which is not local domain

Comment: @王仁宏 I don't think so. If it is CORS issue, then CORS error will be notified in console right?

Comment: If it was a CORS issue then there would be an error on the console.

Comment: LOAD method is working perfectly. GET and POST only making issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `fail` handler so you can see what errors jQuery reports:

```js
let url = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/5b0c30b2-1069-4640-9bb6-18ceb95c25c4";
$.get(url, function(data) {
  alert(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
  console.log(`error: ${error}`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It says:

> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

The server is reporting:

> ```
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> ```

but the body:

> ```
> Sun Jan  3 18:05:31 IST 2021
> ```

… isn't JSON.

---

**Change the server side code so it reports the correct content-type** (probably `text/plain`) or **encodes the data as JSON**.

---

For the sake of completeness, I'll mention that you can tell jQuery to override the `Content-Type` with the parameter after the success function, but that is hacking around the problem instead of fixing the cause so I don't recommend it.

```js
let url = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/5b0c30b2-1069-4640-9bb6-18ceb95c25c4";
$.get(url, function(data) {
  alert(data);
}, "text").fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
  console.log(`error: ${error}`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```